# why doesn't PEAR use absolute paths?

Tags: php, pear

Why does PEAR do this:

```
require_once 'HTML/QuickForm2/Exception.php';
```

Instead of this?:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Exception.php';
```

The only thing I could find on the subject is this:

https://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=17517

It's supposed to be "completely the opposite direction of PEAR standards and design guidelines". My question is...  why?

Comment: Since when 'HTML/QuickForm2/Exception.php' is absolute path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEAR heavily relies on the include path, which makes it possible to overwrite classes by simply prepending another directory to the include path.

Example:

```
require_once 'Foo/Bar.php';
```

would look for `Foo/Bar.php` in each of the directories specified in `include_path`. If you want to provide your own patched `Foo/Bar.php`, you can simply do a

```
set_include_path(__DIR__ . '/patches/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

and create a file `Foo/Bar.php` in the `patches/` directory. The library classes you're using would now automatically use your custom `Foo_Bar` class, without needing any modification.