# PEAR and absolute paths

Tags: php, pear

In [why doesn't PEAR use absolute paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516575/why-doesnt-pear-use-absolute-paths) it's stated that PEAR doesn't use absolute paths so people can overwrite select PEAR libs with their own. Is that the only reason? And if so is there any evidence that people actually do that?

I mean, it seems like using absolute paths would resolve a lot of issues people have with using PEAR libs and if the only reason for not using absolute paths is a use-case that no one actually utilizes it seems like PEAR would be better off using them.

(I don't consider this question a duplicate but more as a followup; posting in the other question likely wouldn't get me any responses since that question's already been answered, so I post this new question)

Comment: and if pear used absolute paths, then it'd be impossible to test code with alternate versions, or have multiple versions to support different aps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are people doing that.

At work, we sometimes need specific patches for pear packages that have not been released yet in official versions. So we overwrite some files only by having another directory with patched php files in addition to the system-wide pear installation.